# Trying to search one table using the value from another table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to program a lookup tool in PHP with SQL database.

```
$sql="SELECT  
         ID, 
         switch, 
         vlan, 
         circuit_id 
      FROM vlan 
      WHERE switch 
      LIKE LOWER('%" . $name .  "%') OR vlan='" . $name ."' 
      ORDER BY vlan";
```

then further down I have this to put the results into variables:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $switch  =$row['switch'];
      $vlan=$row['vlan'];
      $circuitID=$row['circuit_id'];
      $ID=$row['ID'];
```

What I am wanting to do is take the switch reply and use that to do another query on a different table named router and return that information.

I have been searching for a few days and all of my searches ended up here but didnt seem to quite fit. I apreciate any help you can give.

**UPDATE**
With some great answers I finally got this to work. Here is how I did it. Thanks for the help.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $switch  =$row['switch'];
      $vlan=$row['vlan'];
      $circuitID=$row['circuit_id'];
      $ID=$row['ID'];
      $sql2 = "SELECT IPAddress FROM router 
                WHERE switch LIKE '%".$switch."%'
                LIMIT 1";         
      $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
      $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
      $IPAddress = $row2['IPAddress'];
```

Probably real ugly to the more experienced but it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I dont get your problem. Have you tried `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM router WHERE switch = "' . $switch . '"';` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be highly inefficient to run a secondary lookup query in a loop.

What you want is a simple `JOIN` between your two tables based on the `switch` field. What this will do is bring the linked rows in your `router` table alongside the rows in your `vlan` table where values in the `switch` column match up:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT   a.id, a.switch, a.vlan, a.circuit_id, b.ipaddress
    FROM     vlan a
    JOIN     router b ON a.switch = b.switch
    WHERE    a.switch LIKE "%' . strtolower($name) . '%" OR vlan = "' . $name . '"
    ORDER BY a.vlan';
```

Then in your same fetch loop, you'll be able to access the linked values from your `router` table without having to run extra database calls:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $switch  =$row['switch'];
     $vlan=$row['vlan'];
     $circuitID=$row['circuit_id'];
     $ID=$row['ID'];
     $ipaddress = $row['ipaddress'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, wasnt able to try it till today.

Answer (score 0):

How many results do you expect? If there's more than one result, you might need to point which row exactly you want to take. Since it's fetch_array, your $row['switch'] or $switch value is still an array. var_dump it for keys and use the key, i.e.

```
SELECT `col` FROM `router` WHERE `switch` = '$switch[1]'
```

Comment: Would only be one result per switch. On the router table there is a switch col and an IP Address col the IP address is what I am wanting.

Comment: You'd better use fetch_assoc instead of fetch_array, then SELECT `ip` FROM `router` WHERE `switch` = '$switch'

Comment: Think I almost have it, just one quick stupid question that is confusing me. Where do I add that select? Do I add another search like
    $sql2 = "SELECT `IPAddress` FROM `router` WHERE `switch` = '$switch'";
    $name = mysql_query($sql2);

Comment: Yep. mysql_query function accepts only one query, so you need another one var to be mysql_queried :)